# Eclipse Application launch config throws InjectionException after changing target definition from Eclipse Neon (4.6) to Photon (4.8)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, e4, equinox

I'm developing some Eclipse plugins (based on xtext) and I tried to update the target definition from 4.6 Neon to 4.8 Photon.

I have a launch configuration that launches an Eclipse IDE with my plugins loaded. After updating the target definition, the launch configuration automatically updated the version numbers of the bundles that come from the target definition. Some of the new versions had new dependencies, which I added with the "Add Required Plug-ins" button. "Validate Plug-ins" finds no issues, however, when I run this launch configuration, it fails with the following exceptions (stack traces omitted):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-16 17:58:31.550
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '495'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-16 17:58:31.559
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon' from bundle '495'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "ContextProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-16 17:58:31.568
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from bundle '498'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "BindingProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-16 17:58:31.602
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.splitteraddon.SplitterAddon' from bundle '496'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "SplitterAddon.ps": no actual value was found for the argument "EPartService".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-16 17:58:31.612
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.addons.SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon' from bundle '689'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon.eventBroker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. The launch configuration worked fine before. Googling these errors hasn't yielded a helpful result.

Comment: Are you specifying `-clean` in the program arguments in the Run Configuration? Also try `-clearPersistedState`

Comment: I had not. With those at least the Eclipse starts up. I'm still getting tons of errors but they are very different ones, so for now I'd call this issue solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the list of auto-started plugins and their runlevels is corrupted. Opening the "Plug-ins" tab in the launch configuration and pressing the "Restore Defaults" button should fix the problem.

If you customized the list of plugins/features you will have to repeat that. (You can store the launch config in a file in the Common tab, make a backup and compare it with the result to make your life easier).

The same problem can also happen with products. In this case, the solution is to open the "Configuration" tab of the product configuration, click the "Remove All" button under "Start Levels", and click "Add Recommended".